# How can I simplify a lengthy smartsheet function to sum a column based on specific criteria?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am a trainee who's currently working on smartsheet and I would like to find a better way to do this function :

```
=SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 9) +
 SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 8) +
 SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 7) + 
SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 6) + 
SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 5) + 
SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 4) + 
SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 3) +
 SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 2) + 
SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", [Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 1))
```

As you can see, the aim of this function is to sum the column "quantité" if some criteria are met. One of the issue, is that i must sum the quantity for the past 31 days. But as you can see above, it's way to long this way...

I've never used this tool before and I have no idee why the Function "Or" does not work. If anyone got some information I would be very Grateful..

Regards,
HUCHR

I already thy this :

```
=SUMIFS(Quantité:Quantité, [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8", OR([Date mouvement]:[Date mouvement], TODAY() - 9, TODAY() - 8, TODAY() - 7, TODAY() - 6, TODAY() - 5, TODAY() - 4, TODAY() - 3, TODAY() - 2, TODAY() - 1), [Bloc de l'emprunteur]:[Bloc de l'emprunteur], "Bloc 8 H-X", TODAY() - 0)
```

but it did not works.

R

Comment: This type of question is not  really appropriate for Stack Overflow (SO). SO is a venue  for coding-related questions -- e.g., if you were using a programming language like Python to access data in Smartsheet, then you could get help with that type of scenario here on SO. Questions like yours (about using the Smartsheet user interface) should be posted to the **Smartsheet Community** forum. I'd suggest that you post your question to the **Formulas and Functions** area of that forum, as you're more likely to get help there: https://community.smartsheet.com/categories/formulas-and-functions.